# csvファイルを集計してエクセルシートに自動でまとめる場合の実装

Tags: macos, vba, excel

Macにて、csvファイルから、エクセルの定型の集計フォーマットに記載する処理を
いくつものcsvにファイルに対して繰りかえし実行する場合、
どういう実装にするのが一般的でしょうか。

パターン１

```
1.csvファイルをRで読み込み
2.集計済みcsvファイルを保存
3.クリップボードに読み込み
4.エクセルシートにはりつけ
```

パターン２

```
1.AppleScriptでVBAの開始命令をする
2.VBAを用いて、csvファイルを読み込み、計算する
```

パターン３

```
その他
```

パターン2でとりかかりかけたのですが、Windowsでしか動かない関数などが多いため、
あまりスマートな方法ではないのかもしれないと思い、
皆様、このような処理はどう解決されているのか知りたく、質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac ならばシェルスクリプトなどはどうでしょう
シェルスクリプトならばパイルを活用して自動で並列処理になるためとても便利です